Apple pay , stabilize connection with express.js
I want to establish a connection with the Apple servers, from the client I obtain the validationURL URL, after which I send that URL to express.js to be validated, for each Request to apple pay servers, I have implementen an httpsAgent
import axios from "axios";
import https from "https";
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
cert: process.env.VALIDATE_APPLE_MERCHANT_SESSION.replace(/\n/g, "\n"),
keepAlive: true,
});
export const validateAppleMerchant = async (validationURL, merchantAuth, domain) => {
try {
const payload = {

  merchantIdentifier: process.env.MERCHANT_ID_APPLE,

  displayName: procesos.env.NANME_DISPLAYED,

  initiative: "web",

  initiativeContext: domain,

};



console.log("Environment variable value", process.env.VALIDATE_APPLE_MERCHANT_SESSION);

console.log("Execution started with apple pay");

console.log("Payload information", payload);



try {

  const response = await axios.post(validationURL, payload, {

    headers: {

      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",

    },

    httpsAgent: httpsAgent,

  });

  console.log("Session returned from Apple:", response.data);

  return response.data;

} catch (error) {

  throw new Error(`Error validating merchant: ${error.message}`);

}

} catch (error) {
console.error("Error validating merchant:", error);

throw error;

}
};
My question is if that code is correct, or if I should send a key in the agentMy question is if that code is correct, or if I should send a key in the httpsAgent
Thanks!!
A validation response from Apple Pay to the merchant ID that I sent
